# google scholar view all authors

Tags: google-scholar

Google Scholar only allows one to see the first few authors
[image]

this is annoying when you want to get to the other authors google scholar profile on an article with many authors
[image]

Anyone know how to enable all authors to be shown?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You could use the cite option on the paper and the author's names come up. And just copy paste on the search from there. There is no option for generating hyperlinks for all the authors.